Ubuntu 22.04 update disconnects Windows 11 network services
I'm running a Ubuntu 22.04-based file server (Samba to Windows 11 clients). Several weeks ago I ran apt upgrade. My ssh connection dropped part way through the upgrade. From that point I can get a brief ssh, RDP or Samba connection to the file server for about a minute only after rebooting one of three Windows 11 clients (two desktops and one laptop). After a minute or two, the connection drops and further attempts to connect fail. Samba and RDP get no response while ssh gets "Connection refused". I can't find anything in the logs on the file server. If I connect from the file server to a Raspian OS on a Raspberry PI I can ssh back to the file server without dropping. Trying the same thing from the Windows systems fails (sometimes after the one ssh partial connection to the file server from the Raspberry Pi).
Ping from the Windows boxes to the file server continues to work. netstat -rn and ip on the Linux box look normal. The Ethernet device doesn't seem to have changed. Outbound network services from the file server continue (further apt upgrades work). Syslog has no entries for the failed attempts.
I turned off the firewall and AppArmor earlier. Neither made any difference.
Update: The problem seems to be with static networking. Turning DHCP back on fixes the problem. I use an Xfinity router. To get port forwarding to work I overlapped my static systems with the DHCP range. The router seems to be assigning my server IP to another device.

fail2ban or similar firewall configuration installed ?

The comments are not a "chat". Please [edit]  your question and add the information there.

Problem resolved by switching from static IP to DHCP. The problem seems to be with static networking. Turning DHCP back on fixes the problem. I use an Xfinity router. To get port forwarding to work I overlapped my static systems with the DHCP range. The router seems to be assigning my server IP to another device.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
